# Entities won't join even if there is a relation between them when calling find or findOne functions

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm trying to create an entity called author that have an array of already existing entities called books,The function returning value returns the desired value but when I try and see the created entity, the array of book appears with a value of null.
This the code I used for creating the author entity

```
  async create(createAuthorDto: CreateAuthorDto) {
    try {
      const found: Author[] = await this.authorRepo.find({
        where: {
          FirstName: createAuthorDto.FirstName,
          LastName: createAuthorDto.LastName,
        },
      });
      if (found.length != 0) throw Error('This author already exists');
      else {
        const booklist: Book[] = await this.createArray(createAuthorDto.Books);
        console.log('The book list is : ' + booklist);
        return await this.authorRepo.save(
          this.authorRepo.create({
            FirstName: createAuthorDto.FirstName,
            LastName: createAuthorDto.LastName,
            Books: booklist,
          }),
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return error.message;
    }
  }
```

The code for creating the book entity array :

```
  async createArray(booknames: string[]) {
    const books: Book[] = [];
    for (const bookname of booknames) {
      const book: Book | undefined = await this.bookService.findOne(bookname);
      books.push(book);
      console.log(books);
    }
    console.log('The returned value: ' + books);
    return books;
  }
```

The code of author entity:

```
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  ManyToMany,
  JoinTable,
} from 'typeorm';

import { Book } from '../entities/book.entity';

@Entity()
export class Author {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  FirstName: string;

  @Column()
  LastName: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Book)
  @JoinTable()
  Books: Book[];
  //In order to create an object using the book entity I need to define constructors.
  constructor(FirstName: string, LastName: string, Books: Book[]);
  constructor(FirstName: string, LastName: string, Books: Book[], id?: number) {
    this.FirstName = FirstName || '';
    this.LastName = LastName || '';
    this.Books = Books || null;
    this.id = id || null;
  }
}
```

Some pictures of the output results using postman:

The first picture contains the body for the author entity

The second contains the author entity after it was created and saved.

The third picture is the same entity with an empty book array.
[image: Creating the author post request][image: The server return the output of the save method]

[image: The author entity missing the book array although it was created and saved]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add eager to you author entity.
Like this :

```
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  ManyToMany,
  JoinTable,
} from 'typeorm';

import { Book } from '../entities/book.entity';

@Entity()
export class Author {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  FirstName: string;

  @Column()
  LastName: string;
//right here!
  @ManyToMany(() => Book,{eager:true})
  @JoinTable()
  Books: Book[];
  //In order to create an object using the book entity I need to define constructors.
  constructor(FirstName: string, LastName: string, Books: Book[]);
  constructor(FirstName: string, LastName: string, Books: Book[], id?: number) {
    this.FirstName = FirstName || '';
    this.LastName = LastName || '';
    this.Books = Books || null;
    this.id = id || null;
  }
}
```

without the eager, it won't be able to join automatically when you call the find() method.